# File upload on Parse.com isn't working

Tags: c#, android, file-upload, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have been developing a game in Unity3D in C#. So I have set the game to upload the game save file 
to Parse every 2 minutes. When I run the code in Unity it works fine, it saves the game save file locally, and every 2 minutes it uploads it to Parse, it also points to the user who's playing the game. Although when I run the game on a mobile device the file does not upload, I have been refreshing my parse data object in the last half an hour and I still haven't got anything.

Here is the code:

```
void Start () 
{
    if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
    {
        gapTest = true;
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    if(gapTest)
    {
        StartCoroutine(UploadFile());
    }
       if (uploadSaveFile)
    {
        OnZipComplete();
        uploadSaveFile = false;
    }
    else if (createNewSaveFile)
    {
        CreateNewSaveFile();
        createNewSaveFile = false;
    }
}

IEnumerator UploadFile()
{
    gapTest = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (120.0F);
    if(ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
    {
        OnZipComplete();
    }
    gapTest = true;
}

void OnZipComplete()
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameSave").WhereEqualTo("UserObjectId", ParseUser.CurrentUser);

    if (existingGameSave == null)
    {
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

            int resultCount = 0;
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (resultCount > 0)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Found more than one save file for user!");
                }
                else
                {
                    resultCount++;
                    existingGameSave = result;
                    uploadSaveFile = true;
                }
            }

            if (resultCount == 0)
            {
                createNewSaveFile = true;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateExistingSaveFile();
    }
}

private void CreateNewSaveFile()
{
    //upload the file to parse
    zipPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.zip";

    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zipPath);
    ParseFile GameSave = new ParseFile("GameSave.zip", data);

    var gameSave = new ParseObject("GameSave");
    gameSave["UserObjectId"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    gameSave["GameSaveFile"] = GameSave;
    Task saveTask = gameSave.SaveAsync();

    Debug.Log("New Game save file has been uploaded");
}

void UpdateExistingSaveFile()
{
    //upload the file to parse
    UserIdFile = Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserId.txt";
    zipPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.zip";

    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zipPath);
    ParseFile GameSave = new ParseFile("GameSave.zip", data);               
    existingGameSave["GameSaveFile"] = GameSave;
    Task saveTask = existingGameSave.SaveAsync();

    Debug.Log("Existing Game save file has been uploaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem related to permission on android device.

Go to Build Setting > Player Setting > Other Settings, and check "Write Access", by default, it is internal Only which means that the path is for development purpose only.

Try Setting the Write Access as External(SD Card) or add WRITE_ EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission into AndroidManifest.xml. And check Android/file/com.your.appid/files of your sd card if your data is actually getting written on device.

If data is getting written, then it will sure get uploaded on parse.com.